# Using cumsum with mutate

Tags: r, cumsum, mutate

I'm trying to use `cumsum` and `mutate` to create a column showing growth over time. I'm able to produce what I want with `cumsum` on its own by naming the column in question -- but the ultimate goal is to use `across` to apply `cumsum` to an arbitrary number of columns. (Figured I should get it right on one column first ...)

Here's what I'm working with

`dat <- data.frame(year=c("2008", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023"), count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3))`

I can create a cumulative column with

`dat[,"CulmCount1"]<-cumsum(dat$count)`

and thought that I could do the same with

`dat <- dat %>% group_by(count) %>% mutate(CulmCount2 = cumsum(count))`

but that stops the cumulative count after 2015 and doesn't make any sense at all when we get to 2023. (If it didn't work at all, I'd think I was grouping wrong, but I don't understand why it stops cumulating.)

Comment: As you apply grouping, cummulative sum is reset for every group. Your `dplyr` pipeline generates `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 6, 9, 0, 4, 6, 12)`  for `CulmCount2`, which seems fine. Could you please add your desired output?

Comment: to use `across` just use `cumsum` on ungrouped data, the rest is straightforward `dplyr`: `dat |> mutate(across({tidy-select-statement}, cumsum))`

Comment: Thank you, all! I wasn't grasping what grouping was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `cumsum` directly, no grouping needed:

```
dat <- dat |> mutate(ct = cumsum(count))

assertthat::are_equal(dat$CulmCount1, dat$ct) #TRUE
```

Note: The `cumsum` values look kind of funny in your `group_by` version if you just look at them in the order they appear in `dat`. But remember that you're grouping by `count`, so all the 2's go together, the 3's go together, etc.

Try

```
data |> 
  arrange(count) |> 
  group_by(count) |> 
  mutate(CulmCount2 = cumsum(count))
```

and it'll be a lot clearer to see what was going on with your code.